# Error with the dictionary in python

Tags: python, input, dictionary, for-loop

I am parsing a file and I want to built a dictionary containing the name and the value chosen by the user. As I have many names I want to show to the user the name for which he will chose the age:

```
Choose the age of Jack
choose the age of Kate
...
```

here is the code I wrote :

```
list_param = {}
for param in o["persons"]:
   list_param.update({param["name"]: input("choose the age of", param["name"], " :\n" )})
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError: [raw_]input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

How can I fixe it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you expect input() accepting more than one parameter? Either use string contatenation or string interpolation.

Comment: @user1833746 btw, it's `concatenation` :P

Comment: @user1833746: most likely because `print()` *does*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `input("choose the age of", param["name"], " :\n" )`

With: `input("choose the age of "+ param["name"]+ "  :\n" )`

Or even: `input("choose the age of %s:\n" % param["name"])`

`input()` accepts one string, you're thinking about outputting using `print` with commas, you cant do this. Concatenate the strings into one.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
input("choose the age of %s\n" % param["name"])
```

Search the documentation for string interpolation.